# Ubuntu doesnt boot after virtualbox VDI resize to get more disk space

Tags: boot, virtualbox

Created VDI with default 10GB size with dynamic allocation enabled but disk were not expanded automatically even after getting Out Of Disk Space error so I had to manually go to Virtualbx settings and increaed VDI size to 50GB but after that Ubuntu did not load as it was getting blank screen with a cursor blink

Comment: it is because the drive was expanded without expanding the filesystem as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow Below steps

1. Boot Ubuntu with Live CD
2. Open Disks App
3. Click on Paritions shows up on the screen
4. Options -> resize option -> fill max available size
5. Options -> Repair File System

Now reboot your Live CD to get into existing installed Image and now you should see Ubuntu Login Screen

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: In your step 3. I resized partition 2 from 10GB to max! Still not working. I think my issue is more severe. I resized the VM when I did not have enough dist space on my macOS host! Wish your step 3 was more clear! especially when you have multiple partitions.

Comment: Same issue as @chikitin.
However, using gparted in step 4 instead fixed my virtual disk.
I also did the 5th step, not sure if it was needed.