# VirtualBox VM black screen after disk resize

Tags: virtualbox, resize, storage

My VM was running out of space (I use Virtualbox) thats why I decided to inrease the storage size

[resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqCJq.png)

So I resized it using this screen but after that I couldn't fully boot up my VM again. What could've caused this? I cant even undo this change and there is no way I can boot the machine.

[blackscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpRsO.png)

After the ubuntu text at the bottom all I see is this black screen. Any help?

This is my VM details
[vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDsNz.png)

EDIT:
Now I did some stuff and it asks my security password on a black screen and after that I get this messgae:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqIUI.png)

after pressing  control alt f1 in that screen I get this:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvpbh.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1286736/1450095 ,

The drive was expanded without expanding the filesystem as well.

Expand your partitions to boot:

```
Follow Below steps

1. Boot Ubuntu with Live CD
2. Open Disks App
3. Click on Paritions shows up on the screen
4. Options -> resize option -> fill max available size
5. Options -> Repair File System

Now reboot your Live CD to get into existing installed Image and
now you should see Ubuntu Login Screen
```

Comment: To extend KhalfaniWs answer:
Heres a tutorial for his first step: http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/#prettyPhoto